# Google Maps and React - style map controls

Tags: reactjs, typescript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

```js
import { GoogleMap, useLoadScript } from '@react-google-maps/api';
import { IGoogleCredentials } from '../../context';
import { googleMapsContainer } from './droppoint-map.css';

export interface IDroppointMapProps {
    googleCredentials: IGoogleCredentials;
}

export function DroppointMap({ googleCredentials }: IDroppointMapProps) {
    const { isLoaded, loadError } = useLoadScript({
        googleMapsApiKey: googleCredentials.googleMapsApiKey
    });

    if (loadError) return <p>{`Error loading google maps: ${loadError.message}`}</p>;
    if (!isLoaded) return <p>Loading maps ...</p>;
    return (
        <div>
            <GoogleMap
                mapContainerClassName={googleMapsContainer}
                zoom={8}
                center={{ lat: 56.154839, lng: 10.19038 }}
            />
        </div>
    );
}
```

[map result screendump](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Km4vM.png)

I really want to be able to change the size of the zoom controls and the "Map" and "Satellite" buttons in the top left corner. I have no idea on how to go about that. The map style prop could perhaps help me out but I can't seem to find any documentation on how to do this. the `@react-google-maps/api` package doesn't seem to allow to even disable the ui controls.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add e.g. `options={{ controlSize: 10 }}` to set the controls to size 10.

```
<GoogleMap options={{ controlSize: 99 }}
           mapContainerClassName={googleMapsContainer}
           zoom={8}
           center={{ lat: 56.154839, lng: 10.19038 }} 
/>
```

You can see it in [a code sanbox here](https://codesandbox.io/s/react-google-maps-api-forked-kyvp21?file=/src/index.js:2445-2474)

The `@react-google-maps/api` [github page](https://github.com/JustFly1984/react-google-maps-api/blob/develop/packages/react-google-maps-api/src/GoogleMap.tsx) shows that it supports a props object that is the type of - `options?: google.maps.MapOptions | undefined`.
Looking at the [google maps api](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference/map?hl=en#MapOptions) description of that, it has a `controlSize` attribute that can be set, that will change the size of the controls.

You can also disable the interface in the options by setting `disableDefaultUI: true` in the options object.